# How to fill a field with the ranking of another field for a shapefile attribute table in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro

I want to add a field ("FreqRank") in my attribute table with the rank of the field "COUNT", so it was sorted descendingly (see below).

[image]

I tried the code here from another post below (https://community.esri.com/thread/213033-code-field-based-on-rank-of-another-field), but it just give me the OBJECTID.

```
#Codeblock:

rank = 0
lastValue = None

def getNextRank(value):
  global rank
  global lastValue
  if value == lastValue:
    return rank
  else:
    rank += 1
    lastValue =value
    return rank
```

Comment: Code added in the body

Comment: Is my question still closed? Do I need to repost this question? Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that your table is permanently sorted on the COUNT field? As indicated in the link you reference. Because if it isn't sorted, you can't use Calc Field like you are. It'll need to be some 2 step code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/tables/sort-records-in-a-table.htm) to sort your table permanently and use the code above as @Khibma suggests.

Or, This could be done easily with using [cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/data-access-using-cursors.htm) and ArcPy

if you dont have ArcPy experience, you can extract the attribute table by [table to excel tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-excel.htm)

insert your rankings and join that table back to attribute table by using ObjectID as common field

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution using modelbuilder and a python iterator, it takes advantage of sorting the data into an in-memory workspace, compute the rank sequence then simply joins back the data.

[image: Model]

Below is some test data and you want to sort in a descending manner by the field "someNumber". This creates the permanently sorted version of your data which you can build your rank field against.

[image: Sample data]

The model then adds a numeric field called rank and then runs the following field calculate on rank field:

[image: Field Calculate tool]

Below is the code block:

```py
import itertools
aniterator = itertools.count(1,1)
def rank(field):
    return next(aniterator)
```

Finally the model joins the rank field in the temporary in-memory table to the input data using the someNumber field. The end result is this:

[[image: Results4]